# Definition of $T_pM$ where $p \in \partial M$

Tags: differential-geometry

The following excerpt is from Tu's textbook:

A germ of smooth functions at $p$ is an equivalence class of such functions. With the usual addition, multiplication, and scalar multiplication of germs, the set $C^\infty_p(M)$ of germs of $C^\infty$ functions at $p$ is an $\mathbb R$-algebra. The tangent space $T_pM$ at $p$ is then defined to be the vector space of all point-derivations on the algebra $C^\infty_p(M)$.

**For example, for $p$ in the boundary of the upper half-plane $\mathcal H^2$, $\partial/\partial x|_p$ and $\partial/\partial y|_p$ are both derivations on $C^\infty_p(\mathcal H^2)$**...

I am unsure about the last bolded statement. I agree that $\partial/\partial y|_p$ exists in the positive $y$-direction, but it is not well-defined for the negative $y$-direction (i.e. $-\partial/\partial y|_p$ is not well-defined.) Can anyone help me understand this concept?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu defines $T_pM$ as the vector space of all point-derivations on the algebra $C_p^\infty(M)$. A *derivation* is a more abstract concept than an ordinary directional derivative for smooth functions $f  : U \to \mathbb R$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$ or open in $\mathcal H^n$.

In your example the ordinary directional derivatives $\partial/\partial x|_p$ and $\partial/\partial y|_p$ are derivations on $C_p^\infty(\mathcal H^2)$ and they form a basis of $\mathcal H^2$. We do not *need* to regard $-\partial/\partial x|_p$ and $-\partial/\partial y|_p$ as directional derivates, they are certainly derivations in the formal sense.

Nevertheless note that *all* directional derivatives $\partial/\partial v|_p$ with $v \in \mathbb R^2$ are defined. In fact
$$\partial/\partial v|_p = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(p+hv) -f(p)}{h}$$
where we of course only take $h$ such that $p + hv \in \mathcal H^2$. If $v \in \mathcal H^2$, then this requires $h \ge 0$, if $v \notin \mathcal H^2$, then it requires $h \le 0$. This shows that as expected $\partial/\partial{(-v)}|_p = -\partial/\partial v|_p$.